# Sample code in angularjs, to read and write text file

Tags: angularjs

I am completely new to this.The solutions that I am getting from internet is reading the file and displaying as it is, but I want to read the file line by line.

Comment: what do you mean by reading and writing text files? what are the text files?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where are the text files located, on the client or on the server?

Comment: @YerkenThe files are in my local system

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = this.result.split('\n');
for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
console.log(lines[line]); }
```

with `\n` you can split a file at his linebreaks.
Your question was very vague but this is the solution when you want to output a file line by line.
To get this into Context:
First we need to input a file, we can achieve this via HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="filename">
```

Now create a js function to grab this file:

```
document.getElementById('filename').onchange = function(){
// declare file variable
var filevar = this.files[0];
//the Reader:
  var datareader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
  };
```

I already included a FileReader, as you can see
  Now you can combine this to a full function:

```
document.getElementById('filename').onchange = function(){

  var filevar = this.files[0];

  var datareader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(progressEvent){

     var lines = this.result.split('\n');
    for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
      console.log(lines[line]);
    }
  };
  datareader.readAsText(filevar);
};
```

This is a bit tutorialish so sry, but i guess it helps more then just Code.

Comment: Thanks it worked for reading the input file. How to cretae an output text file?

Comment: @chkiriti That one is rather hard since you can't do it crossbrowser with JS only. You could save the data on a server and use a serverside language to save it, you could also use Cookies or an API ... But just with js it is not possible, since it can only operate inside the browser and not on the actual client

Comment: @chkiriti You also could provide a Download Link, didnt mention it since it is not actual saving, if you want i can edit my answer and provide you with the syntax